# JavaScript date duration object methods not available in MarkLogic Query Console

Tags: marklogic

I tried to execute this methods, but it says ".add" not defined. any help please

```
var v1 = xs.yearMonthDuration("P3Y7M");
var v2 = xs.yearMonthDuration("P1Y4M");

v2.add(v1)
```

---

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. If I run this on ML8.0-3 it will give me the expected outcome: `(P4Y11M)` What version of ML are you using?

Comment: pasted it into marklogic console, working for me -> marklogic-8